# Coincap v2 api doesn't return any OHLC data

Tags: python, api

I'm trying to implement the CoinCap API 2.0 for a home project (link to doc added below). For this project I need OHLC data and their documentation implies that I can request this data with or without an api-key (I do have a key when making my requests).

No data is received from the 'candles' endpoint. Every other endpoint does return data. I've tried some python packages (both [python-coincap](https://pypi.org/project/python-coincap/) and [py-coincap-client](https://pypi.org/project/py-coincap-client/)) and multiple requests like the code given below.

The python code used to make the call:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.coincap.io/v2/candles?exchange=kraken&interval=h8&baseId=ethereum&quoteId=bitcoin&start=1528410925604&end=1528411045604"

payload={}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Result:

```
{"data":[],"timestamp":1683222548421}
```

The code is copied from the api documentation: https://docs.coincap.io/

I'm trying to get some clearance about the cause of the problem. I'm asking this question here, because the support from their side is non-existent and I want to learn from what is happening.

I'm leaning towards the possibility that the cause is something on their side of the request that isn't working like it should, which is not shocking when it comes to a free crypto api. But if it could be anything else other then that, I would like to know what that cause could be.

Comment: I do not see smth wrong with your code. I also tried their examples and the responses are empty. Perhaps as you said this is something on their side.

Comment: @kakou Thanks for your comment. I edited my question to include my solution.

Comment: @Bais I have exactly the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone experiancing the same problem.

The problem with coincap is probably at their side. So I looked for alternatives for the coincap API and found [cryptowatch](https://cryptowat.ch/). I've implemented this into my project instead of coincap.